# How to get encrypted password value in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to change the password of a user for this i need to check that old password of that user does match with the value i am getting from html "oldpass" text box. If the existing password value and "oldpass" value matches the new password will be updated in database.The password value i am getting from the database is encrypted.

$userpass = User::where('id', '=', Session::get('userid'))->get(array('password'));
The problem is that $userpass returns a null value .

Here is the code:

```
    $oldpass = Hash::make(Input::get('oldpass'));//Getting password from html form
    $userpass = User::where('id', '=', Session::get('userid'))->get(array('password'));//Getting password value from database Users table
    if ($oldpass === $userpass) {

         User::where('id', '=', Session::get('userid'))
            ->update(array(
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('newpass'))
    ));

    } else {
        Return View::make('changepass.changepass')
                        ->with('errormessage', 'Password does not match');
    }
```

Comment: "hash" and "encrypted" is two completely different terms. A hash cannot (and should not) be decryptable. An encrypted string has to be decryptable. You cannot decrypt a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems here.

1. On one hand, `$userpass` is returning null because `get()` is not the appropiate function to fecth a column. You can use pluck for that (see the [query builder docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries))

   Anyway you can just call the attribute once you fetch the user like:

   `$userpass = User::find(Session::get('userid'))->password;`
2. You are trying to compare a hashed password with a plain password. Laravel uses [Guard](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Auth.Guard.html)
   by default to manage user Authentication and Guard uses `Hash::make` to store it. You should compare hashes with:

   `Hash::check($oldpass, $userpass)`

You could also just check with Guard the user credentials are correct with `Auth::validate($credentials)` (see [Laravel Security](http://laravel.com/docs/security)) and then change the password like:

```
if(Auth::validate('id' => Session::get('userid'), 'password' => Input::get('oldpass'))){
  //Assuming user was authenticated before. If not use Auth::attempt instead of validate
  Auth::user()->password = Hash::make(Input::get('newpass')); 
} else {
    Return View::make('changepass.changepass')
                    ->with('errormessage', 'Password does not match');
}
```

Comment: Thanx Andion, now i can get the value of password.But the hash value of $oldpass(entered in the old password text box)is not same as of hash value saved in database, even i am generating the hash value for a same string.Is it the case that hash value is generated different each time for same string?

Comment: If your users where created using this same Laravel app (and using the default config) it should work. In fact you can also use Hash::check('clearpassword', $hashedPassword)). Are they external/previously generated users? Are you able to log in with your pass?

Comment: @poras The hashed password will always be different, even if the plain password is the same as another one.

Comment: @user2094178 is right so you always have to do it with Hash::check

Comment: @Andion Yes they are previously generated users and i am able to login in with the same.Below is the code i am using to generate a user.

Comment: @Andion Here is the code:--function submitSignup()$validation = User::validateSignup(Input::all())if($validation->fails()){return Redirect::route('signup')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();}else{$signup = new User;$signup->username = Input::get('username');$signup->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));$signup->firstname = Input::get('first_name');$signup->lastname = Input::get('last_name');$signup->email = Input::get('email');$signup->contact = Input::get('contact');$signup->save(); return Redirect::to('index')
->with('message', 'The sign-up request submitted successfully');

Comment: Then the abobe code should work `Hash::check($oldpass, $userpass)` to check if the password is correct.